# Error to integrate HMS in Android Studio , SignInCenter not defined

Tags: java, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services

At the time of implementing the HMS the "SignInCenter" function is not recognized, I have already added all the imports indicated in the documentation but it still does not work.

[Line With Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfKcr.png)

[Imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK5uX.png)

Comment: Please provide more details. Where did you see this "SignInCenter" function? If you are integrating Huawei Account Kit, please refer to this document: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/account-introduction-v4

Answer (score 0):

there has no this function named "SignInCenter" in the API documentation, if you want to use Account kit, here is github codelab link:
https://github.com/HMS-Core/huawei-account-demo

1.call the signIn with the Android standard interface startActivityForResult();

```
private void signIn() {
    mAuthParam = new HuaweiIdAuthParamsHelper(HuaweiIdAuthParams.DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_PARAM)
            .setIdToken()
            .setAccessToken()
            .createParams();
    mAuthManager = HuaweiIdAuthManager.getService(HuaweiIdActivity.this, mAuthParam);
    startActivityForResult(mAuthManager.getSignInIntent(), Constant.REQUEST_SIGN_IN_LOGIN);
}
```

2.get the result whit onActivityResult().

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_SIGN_IN_LOGIN) {
            //login success
            //get user message by parseAuthResultFromIntent
            Task<AuthHuaweiId> authHuaweiIdTask = HuaweiIdAuthManager.parseAuthResultFromIntent(data);
            if (authHuaweiIdTask.isSuccessful()) {
                AuthHuaweiId huaweiAccount = authHuaweiIdTask.getResult();
                Log.i(TAG, huaweiAccount.getDisplayName() + " signIn success ");
                Log.i(TAG,"AccessToken: " + huaweiAccount.getAccessToken());
                validateIdToken(huaweiAccount.getIdToken());
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "signIn failed: " + ((ApiException) authHuaweiIdTask.getException()).getStatusCode());
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_SIGN_IN_LOGIN_CODE) {
            //login success
            Task<AuthHuaweiId> authHuaweiIdTask = HuaweiIdAuthManager.parseAuthResultFromIntent(data);
            if (authHuaweiIdTask.isSuccessful()) {
                AuthHuaweiId huaweiAccount = authHuaweiIdTask.getResult();
                Log.i(TAG, "signIn get code success.");
                Log.i(TAG,"ServerAuthCode: " + huaweiAccount.getAuthorizationCode());

                /**** english doc:For security reasons, the operation of changing the code to an AT must be performed on your server. The code is only an example and cannot be run. ****/
                /**********************************************************************************************/
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "signIn get code failed: " + ((ApiException) authHuaweiIdTask.getException()).getStatusCode());
            }
        }
    }
```